# Inheritance issue using UNET NetworkBehaviour

Tags: c#, inheritance, unity-game-engine, unity-networking

I'm having a headache using the State Synchronization support of UNET in Unity3d 5.

According to documentation http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/UNetStateSync.html
The class should inherit from NetworkBehaviour. Well, I'm doing that way:

```
class Player : Character
abstract class Character : MovingEntity
abstract class MovingEntity : NetworkBehaviour
```

Where, in `Character` I'm storing all player data using the `[SyncVar]` custom attribute. Like this:

```
public abstract class Character : MovingEntity
{
    [SyncVar]
    public string name;
}
```

But in inspector I'm receiving the following error:

`` The type or namespace name `SyncVar' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? ``

and

`` The type or namespace name `SyncVarAttribute' could not be found. Are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference? ``

Not a experient programmer in C#. The fact of the class being inherited from another class that inherits from `NetworkBehaviour` doesn't give me support to do that?

Just FYI, adding `[SyncVar]` on `MovingEntity` (That direct inherits from `NetworkBehaviour`) works just fine.

What I'm doing wrong?
There is any good practice in class inheritance that I'm not doing in this example?

Thanks in advance and sorry for the poor english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have forgotten to add the using directive in one of your file:

```
using UnityEngine.Networking;
```

This has nothing to do with inheritance. Each c# file need to explicitly state the namespace it is using. Alternatively, you can use the [fully qualified names](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dfb3cx8s(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
[UnityEngine.Networking.SyncVar]
```

Answer (score 0):

*This is not the answer to the main problem in the question, just to help whoever ends up here due coming from google like I did - please don't delete this answer it would have helped me if it was here when I needed it*

If you guys ended up in this page because UNet been deprecated and are getting a reference error for NetworkBehaviour, install package: 
Multiplayer HLAPI

Seems to have solved the dependency issue in one of the packages I'm using. I don't have multiplayer functionality so I don't know if it is working or not. But at least I can still use the package that has a class that inherits from NetworkBehaviour.